# Eliminar información guardada en memoria y actualizar al instante Base de datos en ASP.NET C# MYSQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, manejo-de-memoria, web.config

Habría alguna forma de mediante la configuración del archivo web.config hacer que la web vaya actualizando la información almacenada en la base de datos al instante sin que ralentize la web?

Me explico. Actualmente si modifico un campo de texto de un módulo de la web para que el mismo campo se visualizen los cambios en otro módulo debo cerrar el navegador (si estoy en local, cerrar visual studio) ya que si no lo cerro se muestra el valor anterior que esá guardado en memoria y no el que acabo de insertar. Sería posible hacerlo para todos los módulos de la web?

La conexión a la base de datoss sería algo así:

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="basedatos" connectionString="data source=localhost; 
    database=bbdd; user=root; password=1234" 
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

Muchas gracias de antemno.

Un ejemplo sería lo siguiente:

Tengo en el backend un módulo donde guardo un dato de un usuario de esta forma:

```
 tbFirmaNoticia.Text = editado.Firma;
```

El primer valor es el ID del textbox y el segundo es el campo donde guarda dicho dato. Editado es la clase a la que hace referencia.

Luego en otro módulo del backend tengo lo siguiente:

```
 tbFirmaNoticia.Text = activo.Firma;
```

Donde activo ahora hace referencia a la clase donde se ha guardado el valor anterior. Bien, esto funciona, pero en el segundo campo que he puesto para que se vea lo que acabo de insertar, debo cerrar y volver a entrar.

La clase sería algo así:

```
 protected string firma;

public string Firma
  {
      get
    {
         return firma;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != null)
            firma = value;
    }
  }
```

La cuestión es que no se trata solo de un lugar de la web. Suele pasar en distintos sitios, luego creo que es más bien problema de configuración que no está actualizando ñla base de datos constantement y no de programación.

Comment: Porque debes cerrar la aplicacion tus modulos se encuentran en le mismo sitio? Agrega algo de codigo involucrado y reescribe tu pregunta de una manera mas clara.

Comment: Agrega TODO el código que estás desarrollando para entender por qué el error. Saludos

Comment: Lo que explicas no tiene ningn sentido salvo que implementes algun mecanismo de cache en el desarrollo, o quizas si usas algun servicio REST el cual invocas con GET ya que este por defecto si cache las respuesta, pero usando ado.net simple para asgnar los dato a un textbox eso no deberia generar el problema que mencionas

Comment: He editado el post. Com comento es un problema general. Muchas veces debo cerrar el programa, o si no lo cierro, debo modificar el web.config (poniendo un espacio o lo que sea) Para que se muestren los cambios.